# How to configure HeaderCommentFixer in PHP-CS-Fixer

Tags: php

I'd like to use [`HeaderCommentFixer`](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer/blob/1.12/Symfony/CS/Fixer/Contrib/HeaderCommentFixer.php) provided by [`PHP-CS-Fixer`](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer) but I don't understand how to.

I tried to do something like this:

```
$headerCommentFixer = new HeaderCommentFixer();
$headerCommentFixer->setHeader('test this');

return Symfony\CS\Config\Config::create()
    ->level(Symfony\CS\FixerInterface::NONE_LEVEL)
    ->setUsingCache(false)
    ->fixers([
        ...
        $headerCommentFixer,
        ...
    ])
    ->finder($finder);
```

But I get this error:

> [ErrorException] strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object
>   given

So, how can I configure it?
I also checked [the test](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer/blob/1.12/Symfony/CS/Tests/Fixer/Contrib/HeaderCommentFixerTest.php), but this unfortunately didn't helped me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For version `1.x`:

```
// Configure the fixer
$header = 'test this';
Symfony\CS\Fixer\Contrib\HeaderCommentFixer::setHeader($header)

return Symfony\CS\Config\Config::create()
    ->fixers(array(
        'header_comment' // Enable the fixer as rule
    ));
```

For newer (`2.x` or `dev-master`):

```
$header = 'test this';

return Symfony\CS\Config\Config::create()
    ->setRules(array(
        'header_comment' => array('header' => $header)
    ));
```