# PHP-CS-Fixer: how to remove header DocBlock comments

Tags: php

By mistake I've added DocBlock comments to my files:

```
/**
 * @author      My Name <my@email.com>
 * @copyright   Copyright (C) 2012 - 2015 My App. All rights reserved.
 * @license     Some notes about the license.
 */
```

But this si wrong as I want the header comments set like those:

```
/*
 * This file is part of the My App.
 *
 * Copyright My Name 2012-2016.
 *
 * This code is to consider private and non disclosable to anyone for whatever reason.
 * Every right on this code is reserved.
 *
 * @author My name <my@email.com>
 */
```

Now, I've added the header comment [using PHP-CS-Fixer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35121798/how-to-configure-headercommentfixer-in-php-cs-fixer) but now, how can I remove the old ones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer:^2.0.0`, the header comment can be removed entirely using the following configuration:

```
$config = PhpCsFixer\Config::create()->setRules([
    'header_comment' => [
        'header' => '',
    ],
]);
```

Note how we provide an empty string.